# Using datetime axes, but with changing scales

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to display some data using highcharts which consists of multiple series, however all series share the same sort of data. The xAxis is date-based, and the yAxis is a percentage.

The problem I am having is that the series have a different scale for the xAxis

- Series 1: Historical, daily data
- Series 2-n: Future, annual data (mock ups below only show 1 future series for simplicity)

I would like to show this data on one chart, but with roughly the same amount of space for the historical and future data, which means that the historical is compressed in relation to the future.

I have tried to achieve this using 2 different xAxes, and each series relating back to an xAxis with different pointStart settings.

```
...
series: [{
            name: 'Past',
            color: 'Green',
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2014,6,1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
            data: [...]
     },
     {
            name: 'Future',
            color:'blue',
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2014,7,31),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 365, // one year
            xAxis:1,
            data:[...]

     }
     ...
```

This ends up looking like this:

[image: not what I want]
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dq4d0w2o/

I have roughly mocked up what I would like this to look like:

[image]

As you can see the I would like the xAxis to be contiguous, historical data is daily but at the point where we get to the present, the scale changes to be annual.

Comment: Note: This is not logarithmic data, its linear with 2 different scales!

Comment: See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/dq4d0w2o/1/

Comment: @SebastianBochan - Thats brilliant. If you post an answer describing what you changed from my example I'll accept that for sure. One slight issue the mouse-over of the future series seems to go a bit awry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine a `width / left` parameter on xAxis.

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/dq4d0w2o/1

Comment: This plays havoc with the tooltip! Possibly a highcharts bug, but unusable as it currently is as the tooltip is a must for me. On another note, I would have kind of hoped this answer was more than just a link-only.

Comment: Indeed the problem is with tooltip I reported it here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3346, but you can disable defualt tootlip, catch [mouseover](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver) on point and display html custom div (positioned absolutely)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I also found a similar bug reported: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2062